# Fatal error: Call to a member function getPayment() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Express/Review.php on line 203

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.7

I am stucked on this error in making transaction through paypal express checkout after redirecting back from paypal.

I found this error in shipping method.

I am using magento 1.7 version.

here is the code where it gives error

```
 protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $methodInstance = $this->_quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance(); // here i get error
        $this->setPaymentMethodTitle($methodInstance->getTitle());
        $this->setUpdateOrderSubmitUrl($this->getUrl("{$this->_paypalActionPrefix}/express/updateOrder"));
        $this->setUpdateShippingMethodsUrl($this->getUrl("{$this->_paypalActionPrefix}/express/updateShippingMethods"));

        $this->setShippingRateRequired(true);
        if ($this->_quote->getIsVirtual()) {
            $this->setShippingRateRequired(false);
        } else {
            // prepare shipping rates
            $this->_address = $this->_quote->getShippingAddress();
            $groups = $this->_address->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
            if ($groups && $this->_address) {
                $this->setShippingRateGroups($groups);
                // determine current selected code & name
                foreach ($groups as $code => $rates) {
                    foreach ($rates as $rate) {
                        if ($this->_address->getShippingMethod() == $rate->getCode()) {
                            $this->_currentShippingRate = $rate;
                            break(2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // misc shipping parameters
            $this->setShippingMethodSubmitUrl($this->getUrl("{$this->_paypalActionPrefix}/express/saveShippingMethod"))
                ->setCanEditShippingAddress($this->_quote->getMayEditShippingAddress())
                ->setCanEditShippingMethod($this->_quote->getMayEditShippingMethod())
            ;
        }

        $this->setEditUrl($this->getUrl("{$this->_paypalActionPrefix}/express/edit"))
            ->setPlaceOrderUrl($this->getUrl("{$this->_paypalActionPrefix}/express/placeOrder"));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You plz make clear about your question and also post the code where you are getting the error so that we can look forward to solve your problem.

The reason behind the error may be you are calling the method getpayment() on object which is not initialize properly.

Comment: hello sandeep, i have updated the code and write a comment // here i get error on that line where i got this error. Any further information u need ? 
Here is details, I added product to cart and then process with paypal express check out after filling information at paypal website it redirect me back to my website and there i get this error...

Comment: Check whether "_quote" is set or not as you are calling "getPayment()" using "_quote" object